# Get data from multiple checkboxes and insert into mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am trying to get data from multiple checkboxes and insert into mysql. The data is inserting alright, but instead of inserting the correct value, it inserts value 'on'.

Here are my codes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="product11"> Product 11

<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="product12"> Product 12

<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="product13"> Product 13

<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="product14"> Product 14

<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="product15"> Product 15

<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="product16"> Product 16
```

I get this via php this way

```
$products = implode(',',$_POST['product']);
```

Comment: Why are you using a comma-separated value? Why aren't you [properly escaping this data](http://bobby-tables.com/)? What is your actual query code?

Comment: the above code in your question is correct, I mean it will return you product12,product13,.......,product16 in string form.. now you should show the rest code also like query and structure of your database table.

Comment: The problem is obviously not the query since the data is being inputed.

Comment: It worked finally. I had a little error on the value attribute. Some of my checkboxes in the actual code had no attribute. Thanks everyone

Comment: @tadman I am using comma separated value because I want to store the data in one table field. I will then explode it and get an array when I need to use it.

Comment: That's really the wrong approach if you're using a relational database. Those columns are extremely painful to search, they can't be effectively indexed, and they violate the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). It's also often the case that your column is insufficiently long to capture all the possible inputs leading to silent truncation, errors, or both.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @tadman Any better suggestion please? Or do I need to have a column for every value, probably in another table

Comment: I realized it will also be incredibly difficult to update the field

Comment: The way you normally do this is with a one-to-many association table and an index to make that perform well under scale and load. This is the fundamentals of relational database design, so if you're not familiar with how to organize things it's worth finding a good book or reference on the subject. A well designed schema will last a long time, will be pleasant to work with, and will make your application run better. A bad schema will lead to nothing but ugly hacks to make it work.